# how can i run the SDK manager after an update

Tags: android, mobile, sdk

My SDK Manager dose not work after an update of my android sdk manager to the last version, the sdk manager.exe run correctly before the update. Now i get this message when i run the android.bat on the command ligne (i have Win7 OS):

```
'C:\Program' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
Chemin d'accès non valide
ERROR: SWT folder '' does not exist.
Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
```

i tried to change my android.bat but there is always the same problem :
this is my android.bat

```
@echo off
rem Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
rem
rem Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
rem you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
rem You may obtain a copy of the License at
rem
rem      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
rem
rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
rem limitations under the License.

rem Useful links:
rem Command-line reference:
rem   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx

rem don't modify the caller's environment
setlocal

rem Set up prog to be the path of this script, including following symlinks,
rem and set up progdir to be the fully-qualified pathname of its directory.
set prog=%~f0

rem Grab current directory before we change it
set work_dir="%cd%"

rem Change current directory and drive to where the script is, to avoid
rem issues with directories containing whitespaces.
cd /d %~dp0


rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
rem set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
set jar_path=lib\sdkmanager.jar;lib\swtmenubar.jar

rem Set SWT.Jar path based on current architecture (x86 or x86_64)
for /f %%a in ('%java_exe% -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a

:MkTempCopy
    rem Copy android.bat and its required libs to a temp dir.
    rem This avoids locking the tool dir in case the user is trying to update it.

    set tmp_dir=%TEMP%\temp-android-tool
    xcopy %swt_path% %tmp_dir%\%swt_path% /I /E /C /G /R /Y /Q > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\common.jar         %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-codec*     %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-compress*  %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-logging*   %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\dvlib.jar          %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\guava*             %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\httpclient*        %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\httpcore*          %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\httpmime*          %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\layoutlib-api.jar  %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\org-eclipse-*      %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\sdk*               %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
    copy /B /D /Y lib\swtmenubar.jar     %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul

    rem jar_path and swt_path are relative to PWD so we don't need to adjust them, just change dirs.
    set tools_dir=%cd%
    cd /d %tmp_dir%

:EndTempCopy

rem The global ANDROID_SWT always override the SWT.Jar path
if defined ANDROID_SWT set swt_path=%ANDROID_SWT%

if exist %swt_path% goto SetPath
    echo ERROR: SWT folder '%swt_path%' does not exist.
    echo Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
    goto :EOF

:SetPath
rem Finally exec the java program and end here.
REM set REMOTE_DEBUG=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
call %java_exe% %REMOTE_DEBUG% -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="%tools_dir%" -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.workdir=%work_dir% -classpath "%jar_path%;%swt_path%\swt.jar" com.android.sdkmanager.Main %*

rem EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i set correctly my java path and classpath in the environment variables :

```
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
```

and i added this line :

```
set java_exe=C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
```

after this lines in my android.bat :

```
rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
```

the SDK Manager.exe run correctly now :D !

Answer (score 1):

Setting `JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25` like Silverstorm said worked for me

Intellij Idea CE 13, Win 7 x64

Answer (score 0):

Your SDK installation is corrupted, 
the best choice is to remove the SDK and install it again to avoid the possibility to encounter other errors and misbehaviours.

If this doesn't fix the problem, make sure to set correctly the java path and classpath in the environment variables

for example

JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

[Read this help](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: i still have the same problem ! can u give me an other solution !

Comment: hi i set correctly my java path and I added this line :

set java_exe=C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
after this lines in my android.bat :

rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
the SDK Manager.exe run correctly now :D !
thanks a lot Silverstorm :D

Comment: No problem. If you have solved the issue remember to check accept on the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please open find_java.bat in the folder "\sdk\tools\lib", in #27 line, check there:

```
find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32 || set arch_ext=64
```

delete the blank between "arch_ext=32" and "||", like "arch_ext=32||", reopen the cmd, and all tools will work fine.

Looks like Google didn't check this on x86